# What's wrong with this query?

Tags: sqlite, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fw_users (id INT(64) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, auth CHAR(64) UNIQUE, money INT(32) DEFAULT '0', unlocks VARCHAR(8000))
```

I can't see any error in it, but SQLite throws an error:

```
Query failed! AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

It doesn't make sense, id IS an integer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`INT(64)` isn't close enough; it *must* be `INTEGER`.

Answer (score 3):

The SQLite notation is `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`. [Docs reference:](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)

> If you declare a column of a table to be [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid), then whenever you insert a NULL into that column of the table, the NULL is automatically converted into an integer which is one greater than the largest value of that column over all other rows in the table, or 1 if the table is empty. Or, if the largest existing integer key 9223372036854775807 is in use then an unused key value is chosen at random.
> [...]
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1(
>   a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
>   b INTEGER
> );
> ```